# Kernel panic issue

Tags: boot, kernel

I'm having a kernel panic problem (*Kernel panic : not syncing attempted to kill init!*) when I try to boot into Ubuntu.  See image for details and specifically the part about not being able to load shared libraries.

Not sure how exactly this happened but I was facing a problem with the Enter key on the keyboard (it didn't seem to be working) and I ended up rebooting a few times without much help.  And then finally when I used an external keyboard and got the Enter key to work again, this kernel panic occurred.

I've looked at other related messages but none of them seemed directly applicable here.

Before this I've had to run fsck a few times while booting.

Here is the image of the final screen showing the issue.

[image]

Comment: You have an IO error on device *sda*, that is a hardware error on that device, so I'd stop trying to boot it; I'd only boot a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media) and work out what device is sda (be it hdd, ssd etc) & check it's health using SMART (or it's drive diagnostics tools).  (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools)  It uses data from chips on the drive thus won't do any damage, but once you know how bad the problem is, you can decide on a plan to fix issues OR spend your energy on getting any data off that's valuable. Don't try and boot/repair it until you know it's health

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran the SMART test and it passed and most of the details in the results seemed to be normal except that there was a read failure in the "extended offline" category (I am assuming that may be because I was actually using the OS while the test was running).

Comment: You should have been using the 'live' (install media) during the test, SMART reads data from the chips and doesn't touch or use the actual media itself (drive/storage). I also see libcrypt; so I'd next `fsck` your partitions; if errors are detected there and fixed your system will likely boot normally, but I'd explore the extended offline messages read failure(s)

Comment: It looks like you've got either 1) NCQ disk errors (have these message occurred for quite some time?), 2) possible bad sectors on the disk, and maybe a `bad block` scan might sort that out, 3) what is the make/model # of your computer, you may have an old BIOS. Show me screenshot(s) of the SMART Data... and then I can make a better determination.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions .  The laptop is a Lenovo G510. The SMART results can be viewed here: https://justpaste.it/6w89v . Not sure how I would be able to run the SMART without involving the drive that seems to be affected. I ran fsck and that fixed whatever errors it found. I ran the badblocks on the drive and it reported 19 bad blocks.